# Is GNUTLS thread safe? Is it according to its own documentation?

Tags: thread-safety, gnutls

From GnuTLS [3.6.6 Manual](https://www.gnutls.org/manual/gnutls.html#How-to-use-GnuTLS-in-applications) (emphasis mine)

> 6.1.5 Thread safety
>
> The GnuTLS library **is thread safe by design**, meaning that objects of
> the library such as TLS sessions, can be safely divided across threads
> **as long as a single thread accesses a single object**. This is
> sufficient to support a server which handles several sessions per
> thread. **Read-only access to objects**, for example the credentials
> holding structures, **is also thread-safe.**

So... it **is not** actually thread safe.
Next paragraph goes on

> A **gnutls_session_t object could also be shared by two threads**, one
> sending, the other receiving. In that case however, **care must be taken
> during key updates and re-handshakes to be handled only by a single
> thread**. The termination of a session should be handled, either by a
> single thread being active, or by the sender thread using gnutls_bye
> with GNUTLS_SHUT_WR and the receiving thread waiting for a return
> value of zero.

In my book this is like stating a lock is un-pickable as long a no one tries to pick it, while advising guard be kept in order to prevent anyone to perform picking activities.

Is my English letting me down here? I'm I wrong about what thread safety means?

Comment: The implication from the documentation is that while the library is thread safe, it could also be used in a way that is not intended by design as long as certain pieces (key updates and re-handshakes are mentioned) are carefully considered.

To expand, the first piece of documentation you reference mentions that the library is thread safe "as long as a single thread accesses a single object". The second piece describes a use case where two threads access a single object, therefore breaking the previously stated rule.

Comment: @LaneTerry, it must be me having an erroneous concept of what thread safety is then. In mi mind, being thread safe means precisely that data objects can be safely shared among threads.OTOH, having functions being safely called from several threads (is that what is being implied?) has nothing to do with thread safety but with reentrancy. Time to brush up on these matters I guess.